# Redirect all subdomains, subpages, and the root domain to themselves on another domain

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, domain, redirection, htaccess

I have done a lot of searching and have tried many things but I have still not managed to find a way of doing this exactly how I want it.

Without having to make an Apache VirtualHost for each subdomain, and either with apache2 (preferably), htaccess or DNS, I would like to redirect:

- `domain.xyz` to `domain.com`
- `domain.xyz/*` to `domain.com/*`
- `*.domain.xyz` to `*.domain.xyz` (so `a.domain.xyz` goes to `a.domain.com` and `b.domain.xyz` goes to `b.domain.com`)
- `*domain.xyz/*` to `*.domain.com/*`

What is the easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Approach 1

**Disclaimer**: I have not tried this first approach , but I think it might work.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.xyz$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

So, the first `RewriteCond` should match the `HTTP_HOST` which will basically be your domain if it ends in `.xyz`. If it does, you just rewrite the request to the `.com` TLD with the same URI.

### Approach 2

There's also another way. You could simply forward any request to a static PHP file, and place the original URL as a parameter to the script and once called, replace the URL to the domain you want. That would imply the following changes:

1. Edit your apache's configuration and put something like this inside. This has been copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214502/how-to-redirect-all-requests-to-index-php-and-keep-the-other-get-params).

   ```
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
   RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
   ```

   This way, any request will be forwarded to a `index.php` file located wherever you defined in your `DocumentRoot` directive.
2. In that file, you'd do something like this:

   ```
   <?php
      $url =  "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
      $escaped_url = htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

      preg_match("/^http:\/\/(.*)\.xyz(.*)$/", $escaped_url, $matches);
      header("Location: http://{$matches[1]}.com{$matches[2]}");
   ?>
   ```

   So you're just matching the original URL (stored inside `$url`) against a regexp and changing the location of the user (via the `header()`) function to the same domain but with different `TLD`. This last try has been tested and works well.